# Let $(u_1, u_2,.., u_n)$ be an AP having common difference $d>0$. Suppose $(u_n)^2$ = $(n^2)(d^2)$ and $u_1$ is negative. If $n = 15$, find the AP.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(u_1, u_2,.., u_n)$ be an AP having common difference $d>0$. Suppose $(u_n)^2$ = $n^2d^2$ and $u_1$ is negative. If $n = 15$, find the AP.

$(u_1)^2 = 1^2 \cdot d^2$

⇒ $u_1 = d$ or $(-d)$

since $d>0$, and $u_1 <0$, we have $u_1 = -d$

unable to proceed further.

Comment: In the statement of the question, it seems that $n$ is not a "running" (variable) index traversing the progression, but a specific value referring to the last element only. Please clarify, because the solution and the answer very much depend on that. More specifically: does the condition $u_n^2=n^2d^2$ apply to **all elements** of the progression or to the **last element only**?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $$(u_2-u_1)^2 = (u_3-u_2)^2 =\cdots =(u_{n}-u_{n-1})^2 =d^2$$ By condition, we have, $$u_1^2 = d^2$$ $$u_2^2 = 4d^2 $$ $$u_3^2 =9d^2$$ and so on..

Consider, $$u_2^2-u_1^2 = 3d^2 =3(u_2-u_1)^2$$ Assuming $u_1 \neq u_2\neq u_3 \neq \cdots u_n$, we have, $u_2+u_1 = 3(u_2-u_1) \Rightarrow 2u_1 = u_2$. We already know that $ u_1 = -d$, so $ u_2 = -2d$. Similarly, $u_3 = -3d, u_4 = -4d, \cdots, u_n =-nd$.

On a side note, you may wonder that the common difference of this A.P is $-d$ and not $d$. This I feel is the only solution that satisfies the given condition. That is why, in the first step, I considered $d^2$. Hope it helps.

Comment: But the question says that the common difference is $d$, not $-d$. So your "answer" doesn't actually answer the posted question. However, it's useful because it shows that this interpretation leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution under the assumption that the condition $u_n^2=n^2d^2$ refers to the last term of the sequence only — I believe that this is what the question means, because otherwise (assuming this formula applies to all terms) we get a contradiction.

First of all, the condition $u_n^2=n^2d^2$ implies $u_n=\pm nd$, so we have two possibilities here. Also, the standard formulas for the terms of an arithmetic progressions gives us $u_n=u_1+(n-1)d$. Let's combine these two equations.

**Case 1:** $u_n=nd$. Then
$$u_1+(n-1)d=nd$$
$$u_1+nd-d=nd$$
$$u_1-d=0$$
$$u_1=d$$
But this is impossible, because we're given that $u_1<0$ and $d>0$.

**Case 2:** $u_n=-nd$. Then
$$u_1+(n-1)d=-nd$$
$$u_1=-n-(n-1)d$$
$$u_1=-(2n-1)d$$
Specifically, with $n=15$, we get $u_1=-29d$, and so the progression is
$$u_1=-29d,\,u_2=-28d,\,u_3=-27d,\,\ldots,\,u_{14}=-16d,\,u_{15}=-15d.$$
Note that
$$(u_n)^2=(u_{15})^2=(-15d)^2=15^2d^2=n^2d^2$$
as required. And as long as $d$ is positive, $u_1$ is negative, also as required.

As you can see, there's not enough information to restore such a progression uniquely — for any positive $d$ we have an arithmetic progression satisfying all conditions of the question.